# Error: submit is not a function with alertify function

Tags: javascript

Let's see if someone could help me solve this problem that I don't understand.

I've been looking to solve a problem for a couple of days, I have a confirmation alertify function.

With an html form I call the alertify function with the onclick event, but in the chrome dev tools it appears that submit is not a function. The Id of the form matches the javascript function and with a console.log the DOM identifies the form correctly.

html form

```
<form name="formulario" id="edit-form" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return showAlertConfirm('¿Está seguro de que desea editar el registro?','edit-form',url)" value="Editar" />
```

javascript function

```
//Funcione alertify para editar/eliminar registro
function showAlertConfirm(message,formId,url) {
  // Prevent the default form submission
  document.getElementById(formId).addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Display the confirmation dialog
  alertify.confirm(
    "ATENCIÓN",
    message,
    function () {
      console.log("ok clicked");
      console.log(formId);
      console.log(document.getElementById(formId));          
      let formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
      formObj.submit();
     
    },
    function () {
      console.log("Cancel clicked"); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        showNotification("Operación Cancelada");        
        // Después de 5 segundos, redirige
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = url;
        }, 5000);
    }, 0); // Espera 5 segundos antes de mostrar la notificación
    }
  );

  // Always return false to prevent the default form submission
  return false;
}
```

Error

```
jscript.js:212 Uncaught TypeError: formObj.submit is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (jscript.js:212:15)
    at Object.callback (alertify.min.js:3:2247)
    at U (alertify.min.js:2:13068)
    at Object.V (alertify.min.js:2:13159)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (alertify.min.js:2:1267)
```

Comment: Its best practice to catch the form submit itself instead of catching click handlers. You can submit the form in various ways, e.g. by pressing enter, that wouldnt trigger `showAlertConfirm `

Answer (score 0):

Try altering the HTML submit button. Remove all references of `submit` from the button,

```html
<input type="button" onclick="return showAlertConfirm('¿Está seguro de quedesea editar el registro?','edit-form',url)" value="Editar" />
```

Ref - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

---

**Original code snippet** (has `form.submit` error)

```js
//Funcione alertify para editar/eliminar registro
function showAlertConfirm(message,formId,url) {
  // Prevent the default form submission
  document.getElementById(formId).addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Display the confirmation dialog
  alertify.confirm(
    "ATENCIÓN",
    message,
    function () {
      console.log("ok clicked");
      console.log(formId);
      console.log(document.getElementById(formId));          
      let formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
      formObj.submit();
     
    },
    function () {
      console.log("Cancel clicked"); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        showNotification("Operación Cancelada");        
        // Después de 5 segundos, redirige
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = url;
        }, 5000);
    }, 0); // Espera 5 segundos antes de mostrar la notificación
    }
  );

  // Always return false to prevent the default form submission
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js"></script>

<form name="formulario" id="edit-form" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return showAlertConfirm('¿Está seguro de que desea editar el registro?','edit-form','https://www.google.com')" value="Editar" />
```

---

**Updated code** (all `submit` references removed - no `form.submit` error)

```js
//Funcione alertify para editar/eliminar registro
function showAlertConfirm(message,formId,url) {
  // Prevent the default form submission
  document.getElementById(formId).addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Display the confirmation dialog
  alertify.confirm(
    "ATENCIÓN",
    message,
    function () {
      console.log("ok clicked");
      console.log(formId);
      console.log(document.getElementById(formId));          
      let formObj = document.getElementById(formId);
      formObj.submit();
     
    },
    function () {
      console.log("Cancel clicked"); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        showNotification("Operación Cancelada");        
        // Después de 5 segundos, redirige
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = url;
        }, 5000);
    }, 0); // Espera 5 segundos antes de mostrar la notificación
    }
  );

  // Always return false to prevent the default form submission
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js"></script>

<form name="formulario" id="edit-form" method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="button" onclick="return showAlertConfirm('¿Está seguro de que desea editar el registro?','edit-form','https://www.google.com')" value="Editar" />
```

Comment: Hi James, thank you for message. I tried removing type='submit' and name='submit'. Ansd removing only name='submit', and in both cases It doesn't submit the form.

Comment: tried removing `id='submit'` also? please remove all traces of the word `submit` from the form and its children.. if it is still not working, what is the type of `formObj`? is it `HTMLFormElement` or something else?

Comment: formId, is the name of the form.
let formObj = document.getElementById(formId); 
I removed all submit even id='submit' 

This is part of the function that I have the issue 
alertify.confirm(
    "ATENCIÓN",
    message,
    function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("ok clicked");
      console.log(formId); 
      console.log(document.getElementById(formId));
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(formId).submit();
    }, 10000);
}, 0);

Comment: In dev tools console I can see this:
ok clicked --> comes from console.log("ok clicked");
jscript.js:210 edit-form --> comes from console.log(formId);
jscript.js:211 <form name=​"formulario" id=​"edit-form" method=​"POST" action=​"#" enctype=​"multipart/​form-data">​…​</form>​  --> comes from console.log(document.getElementById(formId));
here document.getElementById(formId).submit(); It doesn't submit the form
the html button <input class="button" onclick="return showAlertConfirm('¿Está seguro de que desea editar el registro?','edit-form',url)" value="Editar" />

Comment: @joserodriguezan, added code snippets onto the above answer. Please run the code snippet on both of them. The first one has the error while the second one doesn't after removing all `submit` references from form markup.

Comment: Hi James, I did that but does not work as it supposed to be. After submit from javascript Alertify the code must continue in if (isset($_POST["submit"])) { echo 'TEST ---------------'; sleep(10); # retrieve information from form. ?> <script> console.log('hecho'); </script> –

But never arrives here.

Comment: this looks like PHP code, probably the submit handler? but your JS submit error is fixed right?

Comment: Right. Looks like js is working. I'll see what's up with the submit. Thanks James for your help